# PHP Can't Read My XML File Extracted from a Docx File

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, docx

Why can't `simplexml_load_file` read my extracted .**xml** file from a **.docx**?

I unzipped a document and extracted the xml document inside. I want to turn the file into an object for further processing.

**document.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:sl="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/schemaLibrary/2006/main" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" xmlns:c="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" xmlns:lc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/lockedCanvas" xmlns:dgm="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/diagram" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml">
 <w:body>
  <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000001">
   <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Title" />
    <w:rPr>
     <w:b w:val="1" />
    </w:rPr>
   </w:pPr>
   <w:bookmarkStart w:colFirst="0" w:colLast="0" w:name="_w1u6oxrcwo6y" w:id="0" />
   <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0" />
   <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
    <w:rPr>
     <w:b w:val="1" />
     <w:rtl w:val="0" />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">This is a title</w:t>
   </w:r>
  </w:p>
  <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000002">
   <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Subtitle" />
    <w:rPr />
   </w:pPr>
   <w:bookmarkStart w:colFirst="0" w:colLast="0" w:name="_1dpn3qgnm18d" w:id="1" />
   <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="1" />
   <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
    <w:rPr>
     <w:rtl w:val="0" />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">This is a subtitle</w:t>
   </w:r>
  </w:p>
  <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000003">
   <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Title" />
    <w:jc w:val="center" />
    <w:rPr>
     <w:b w:val="1" />
    </w:rPr>
   </w:pPr>
   <w:bookmarkStart w:colFirst="0" w:colLast="0" w:name="_7lt15rmo3kze" w:id="2" />
   <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="2" />
   <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
    <w:rPr>
     <w:b w:val="1" />
     <w:rtl w:val="0" />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">This is a centered title</w:t>
   </w:r>
  </w:p>
  <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="0000000E">
   <w:pPr>
    <w:rPr />
   </w:pPr>
   <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
    <w:rPr>
     <w:rtl w:val="0" />
    </w:rPr>
   </w:r>
  </w:p>
  <w:tbl>
   <w:tblPr>
    <w:tblStyle w:val="Table1" />
    <w:tblW w:w="9360.0" w:type="dxa" />
    <w:jc w:val="left" />
    <w:tblBorders>
     <w:top w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="8" w:val="single" />
     <w:left w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="8" w:val="single" />
     <w:bottom w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="8" w:val="single" />
     <w:right w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="8" w:val="single" />
     <w:insideH w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="8" w:val="single" />
     <w:insideV w:color="000000" w:space="0" w:sz="8" w:val="single" />
    </w:tblBorders>
    <w:tblLayout w:type="fixed" />
    <w:tblLook w:val="0600" />
   </w:tblPr>
   <w:tblGrid>
    <w:gridCol w:w="2340" />
    <w:gridCol w:w="2340" />
    <w:gridCol w:w="2340" />
    <w:gridCol w:w="2340" />
    <w:tblGridChange w:id="0">
     <w:tblGrid>
      <w:gridCol w:w="2340" />
      <w:gridCol w:w="2340" />
      <w:gridCol w:w="2340" />
      <w:gridCol w:w="2340" />
     </w:tblGrid>
    </w:tblGridChange>
   </w:tblGrid>
   <w:tr>
    <w:trPr>
     <w:cantSplit w:val="0" />
     <w:trHeight w:val="420" w:hRule="atLeast" />
     <w:tblHeader w:val="0" />
    </w:trPr>
    <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
      <w:gridSpan w:val="4" />
      <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
      <w:tcMar>
       <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
      </w:tcMar>
      <w:vAlign w:val="top" />
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="0000000F">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:keepNext w:val="0" />
       <w:keepLines w:val="0" />
       <w:pageBreakBefore w:val="0" />
       <w:widowControl w:val="0" />
       <w:pBdr>
        <w:top w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:left w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:bottom w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:right w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:between w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
       </w:pBdr>
       <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
       <w:spacing w:after="0" w:before="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto" />
       <w:ind w:left="0" w:right="0" w:firstLine="0" />
       <w:jc w:val="left" />
       <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
       <w:rPr>
        <w:rtl w:val="0" />
       </w:rPr>
       <w:t xml:space="preserve">This is a table</w:t>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:tc>
   </w:tr>
   <w:tr>
    <w:trPr>
     <w:cantSplit w:val="0" />
     <w:tblHeader w:val="0" />
    </w:trPr>
    <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
      <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
      <w:tcMar>
       <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
      </w:tcMar>
      <w:vAlign w:val="top" />
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000013">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1" />
       <w:widowControl w:val="0" />
       <w:spacing w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto" />
       <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:colFirst="0" w:colLast="0" w:name="_f7vdpbjqbso7" w:id="11" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="11" />
      <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
       <w:rPr>
        <w:rtl w:val="0" />
       </w:rPr>
       <w:t xml:space="preserve">Heading 1</w:t>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
      <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
      <w:tcMar>
       <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
      </w:tcMar>
      <w:vAlign w:val="top" />
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000014">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2" />
       <w:widowControl w:val="0" />
       <w:spacing w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto" />
       <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:colFirst="0" w:colLast="0" w:name="_ybl0p64mnlcd" w:id="12" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="12" />
      <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
       <w:rPr>
        <w:rtl w:val="0" />
       </w:rPr>
       <w:t xml:space="preserve">Heading 2</w:t>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
      <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
      <w:tcMar>
       <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
      </w:tcMar>
      <w:vAlign w:val="top" />
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000015">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:pStyle w:val="Heading3" />
       <w:widowControl w:val="0" />
       <w:spacing w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto" />
       <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:colFirst="0" w:colLast="0" w:name="_btn1lfbm6g85" w:id="13" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="13" />
      <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
       <w:rPr>
        <w:rtl w:val="0" />
       </w:rPr>
       <w:t xml:space="preserve">Heading 3</w:t>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
      <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
      <w:tcMar>
       <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
      </w:tcMar>
      <w:vAlign w:val="top" />
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000016">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:pStyle w:val="Heading4" />
       <w:widowControl w:val="0" />
       <w:spacing w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto" />
       <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:colFirst="0" w:colLast="0" w:name="_sow4hf35zyqw" w:id="14" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="14" />
      <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
       <w:rPr>
        <w:rtl w:val="0" />
       </w:rPr>
       <w:t xml:space="preserve">Heading 4</w:t>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:tc>
   </w:tr>
   <w:tr>
    <w:trPr>
     <w:cantSplit w:val="0" />
     <w:tblHeader w:val="0" />
    </w:trPr>
    <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
      <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
      <w:tcMar>
       <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
      </w:tcMar>
      <w:vAlign w:val="top" />
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000017">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:pStyle w:val="Heading5" />
       <w:widowControl w:val="0" />
       <w:spacing w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto" />
       <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:colFirst="0" w:colLast="0" w:name="_v92g3wnc60wh" w:id="15" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="15" />
      <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
       <w:rPr>
        <w:rtl w:val="0" />
       </w:rPr>
       <w:t xml:space="preserve">Heading 5</w:t>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
      <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
      <w:tcMar>
       <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
      </w:tcMar>
      <w:vAlign w:val="top" />
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000018">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:pStyle w:val="Heading6" />
       <w:widowControl w:val="0" />
       <w:spacing w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto" />
       <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:colFirst="0" w:colLast="0" w:name="_xkh3n1p2b5g8" w:id="16" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="16" />
      <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
       <w:rPr>
        <w:rtl w:val="0" />
       </w:rPr>
       <w:t xml:space="preserve">Heading 6</w:t>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
      <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
      <w:tcMar>
       <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
      </w:tcMar>
      <w:vAlign w:val="top" />
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000019">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:keepNext w:val="0" />
       <w:keepLines w:val="0" />
       <w:pageBreakBefore w:val="0" />
       <w:widowControl w:val="0" />
       <w:pBdr>
        <w:top w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:left w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:bottom w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:right w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:between w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
       </w:pBdr>
       <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
       <w:spacing w:after="0" w:before="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto" />
       <w:ind w:left="0" w:right="0" w:firstLine="0" />
       <w:jc w:val="left" />
       <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
       <w:rPr>
        <w:rtl w:val="0" />
       </w:rPr>
       <w:t xml:space="preserve">Normal Text</w:t>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
      <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
      <w:tcMar>
       <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
      </w:tcMar>
      <w:vAlign w:val="top" />
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="0000001A">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:keepNext w:val="0" />
       <w:keepLines w:val="0" />
       <w:pageBreakBefore w:val="0" />
       <w:widowControl w:val="0" />
       <w:pBdr>
        <w:top w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:left w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:bottom w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:right w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:between w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
       </w:pBdr>
       <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
       <w:spacing w:after="0" w:before="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto" />
       <w:ind w:left="0" w:right="0" w:firstLine="0" />
       <w:jc w:val="left" />
       <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
       <w:rPr>
        <w:rtl w:val="0" />
       </w:rPr>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:tc>
   </w:tr>
   <w:tr>
    <w:trPr>
     <w:cantSplit w:val="0" />
     <w:tblHeader w:val="0" />
    </w:trPr>
    <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
      <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
      <w:tcMar>
       <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
      </w:tcMar>
      <w:vAlign w:val="top" />
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="0000001B">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:keepNext w:val="0" />
       <w:keepLines w:val="0" />
       <w:pageBreakBefore w:val="0" />
       <w:widowControl w:val="0" />
       <w:pBdr>
        <w:top w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:left w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:bottom w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:right w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:between w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
       </w:pBdr>
       <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
       <w:spacing w:after="0" w:before="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto" />
       <w:ind w:left="0" w:right="0" w:firstLine="0" />
       <w:jc w:val="left" />
       <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
       <w:rPr>
        <w:rtl w:val="0" />
       </w:rPr>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
      <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
      <w:tcMar>
       <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
      </w:tcMar>
      <w:vAlign w:val="top" />
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="0000001C">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:keepNext w:val="0" />
       <w:keepLines w:val="0" />
       <w:pageBreakBefore w:val="0" />
       <w:widowControl w:val="0" />
       <w:pBdr>
        <w:top w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:left w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:bottom w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:right w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:between w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
       </w:pBdr>
       <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
       <w:spacing w:after="0" w:before="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto" />
       <w:ind w:left="0" w:right="0" w:firstLine="0" />
       <w:jc w:val="left" />
       <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
       <w:rPr>
        <w:rtl w:val="0" />
       </w:rPr>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
      <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
      <w:tcMar>
       <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
      </w:tcMar>
      <w:vAlign w:val="top" />
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="0000001D">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:keepNext w:val="0" />
       <w:keepLines w:val="0" />
       <w:pageBreakBefore w:val="0" />
       <w:widowControl w:val="0" />
       <w:pBdr>
        <w:top w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:left w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:bottom w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:right w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:between w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
       </w:pBdr>
       <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
       <w:spacing w:after="0" w:before="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto" />
       <w:ind w:left="0" w:right="0" w:firstLine="0" />
       <w:jc w:val="left" />
       <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
       <w:rPr>
        <w:rtl w:val="0" />
       </w:rPr>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
      <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
      <w:tcMar>
       <w:top w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:left w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:bottom w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
       <w:right w:w="100.0" w:type="dxa" />
      </w:tcMar>
      <w:vAlign w:val="top" />
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="0000001E">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:keepNext w:val="0" />
       <w:keepLines w:val="0" />
       <w:pageBreakBefore w:val="0" />
       <w:widowControl w:val="0" />
       <w:pBdr>
        <w:top w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:left w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:bottom w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:right w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
        <w:between w:space="0" w:sz="0" w:val="nil" />
       </w:pBdr>
       <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear" />
       <w:spacing w:after="0" w:before="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto" />
       <w:ind w:left="0" w:right="0" w:firstLine="0" />
       <w:jc w:val="left" />
       <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
       <w:rPr>
        <w:rtl w:val="0" />
       </w:rPr>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:tc>
   </w:tr>
  </w:tbl>
  <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="0000001F">
   <w:pPr>
    <w:rPr />
   </w:pPr>
   <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
    <w:rPr>
     <w:rtl w:val="0" />
    </w:rPr>
   </w:r>
  </w:p>
  <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000020">
   <w:pPr>
    <w:rPr />
   </w:pPr>
   <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
    <w:rPr />
    <w:drawing>
     <wp:inline distB="114300" distT="114300" distL="114300" distR="114300">
      <wp:extent cx="5943600" cy="3962400" />
      <wp:effectExtent b="0" l="0" r="0" t="0" />
      <wp:docPr id="2" name="image2.jpg" />
      <a:graphic>
       <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
        <pic:pic>
         <pic:nvPicPr>
          <pic:cNvPr id="0" name="image2.jpg" />
          <pic:cNvPicPr preferRelativeResize="0" />
         </pic:nvPicPr>
         <pic:blipFill>
          <a:blip r:embed="rId7" />
          <a:srcRect b="0" l="0" r="0" t="0" />
          <a:stretch>
           <a:fillRect />
          </a:stretch>
         </pic:blipFill>
         <pic:spPr>
          <a:xfrm>
           <a:off x="0" y="0" />
           <a:ext cx="5943600" cy="3962400" />
          </a:xfrm>
          <a:prstGeom prst="rect" />
          <a:ln />
         </pic:spPr>
        </pic:pic>
       </a:graphicData>
      </a:graphic>
     </wp:inline>
    </w:drawing>
   </w:r>
   <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
    <w:rPr>
     <w:rtl w:val="0" />
    </w:rPr>
   </w:r>
  </w:p>
  <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000021">
   <w:pPr>
    <w:rPr />
   </w:pPr>
   <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
    <w:rPr>
     <w:rtl w:val="0" />
    </w:rPr>
   </w:r>
  </w:p>
  <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000022">
   <w:pPr>
    <w:jc w:val="center" />
    <w:rPr />
   </w:pPr>
   <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
    <w:rPr>
     <w:rtl w:val="0" />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">This is centered normal text</w:t>
   </w:r>
  </w:p>
  <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000023">
   <w:pPr>
    <w:jc w:val="center" />
    <w:rPr />
   </w:pPr>
   <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
    <w:rPr>
     <w:rtl w:val="0" />
    </w:rPr>
   </w:r>
  </w:p>
  <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" w14:paraId="00000024">
   <w:pPr>
    <w:jc w:val="center" />
    <w:rPr />
   </w:pPr>
   <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
    <w:rPr />
    <w:drawing>
     <wp:inline distB="114300" distT="114300" distL="114300" distR="114300">
      <wp:extent cx="5943600" cy="3670300" />
      <wp:effectExtent b="0" l="0" r="0" t="0" />
      <wp:docPr descr="Points scored" id="1" name="image1.png" />
      <a:graphic>
       <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
        <pic:pic>
         <pic:nvPicPr>
          <pic:cNvPr descr="Points scored" id="0" name="image1.png" />
          <pic:cNvPicPr preferRelativeResize="0" />
         </pic:nvPicPr>
         <pic:blipFill>
          <a:blip r:embed="rId8" />
          <a:srcRect b="0" l="0" r="0" t="0" />
          <a:stretch>
           <a:fillRect />
          </a:stretch>
         </pic:blipFill>
         <pic:spPr>
          <a:xfrm>
           <a:off x="0" y="0" />
           <a:ext cx="5943600" cy="3670300" />
          </a:xfrm>
          <a:prstGeom prst="rect" />
          <a:ln />
         </pic:spPr>
        </pic:pic>
       </a:graphicData>
      </a:graphic>
     </wp:inline>
    </w:drawing>
   </w:r>
   <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
    <w:rPr>
     <w:rtl w:val="0" />
    </w:rPr>
   </w:r>
  </w:p>
  <w:sectPr>
   <w:headerReference r:id="rId9" w:type="default" />
   <w:footerReference r:id="rId10" w:type="default" />
   <w:pgSz w:h="15840" w:w="12240" w:orient="portrait" />
   <w:pgMar w:bottom="1440" w:top="1440" w:left="1440" w:right="1440" w:header="720" w:footer="720" />
   <w:pgNumType w:start="1" />
  </w:sectPr>
 </w:body>
</w:document>
```

**process.php**

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file('document.xml');
print_r($xml);
```

This generates an empty object.

Comment: `SimpleXML` objects are dynamically generated, `print_r()` does not display the entire information. Just read the the children and attributes normally, they should be there as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements with namespace must also be selected with the namespace. Even the root element has a namespace, which is why the object is empty.

```php
$xml = simplexml_load_file($path);
$namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
print_r($namespaces);
$children = $xml->children($namespaces['w']);
print_r($children);
```

Comment: Is there a way to get all the namespaces together? Or do I have to call the namespace at the level of the object.

Comment: I don't know if SimpleXML can do this. I would say no, because technically it makes no sense. Namespaces are meant to logically separate tags/data from each other. Also to avoid conflicts in element and attribute names. The namespace can also be used to decide how elements in a namespace should be processed. For example, the <svg> element in an HTML document has a namespace. This is how the RenderEngine knows that it is SVG. You will have to handle all namespaces one by one. Maybe you can find a package on GitHub that supports you.